# UITableView "swipe to delete" function freezes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I can't figure out why my tableView isn't updating after I tap the delete button.

Once I click it, the table view "freezes". If I click another row, so that the tableview goes to another level of the hierarchy and click back, I can see that the item has been deleted and everything works fine.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    //[tableView beginUpdates];    
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        // Do whatever data deletion you need to do...
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        NSManagedObject *obj = (NSManagedObject *)[entityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:obj];
        NSError *error;
        [managedObjectContext save:&error];

        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:YES];

         [self viewWillAppear:YES];

    }
    //[tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Any input on this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: why did you put the `//[tableView endUpdates];` outside the if and commented it?

Comment: You most definitely should not be calling [self viewWillAppear:YES];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a call to `[tableView endUpdates]` matching the `[tableView beginUpdates]` that is at start of the `if`.

Could it be for this reason that your table freezes?

Comment: ah, I should have caught that one. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Found same issue and stumbled upon this thread. But the reason for the tableview freeze issue was different in our case.

For the sake of posterity:

The UITableViewCell which goes into Edit mode to display the "insert" or "delete" buttons should never have its `userInteractionEnabled` property set to "NO".

By correcting this, the same tableview freezing issue was fixed for us.